# Key Error: "None of [Int64Index...] dtype='int64] are in the columns"

Tags: python, pandas, data-science, data-analysis, boxplot

CODE:-

```
import os
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


class Vizualizer:

    def __init__(self,data,cols):
        self.data=data
        self.cols=cols

    def box_plot(self):
            for col in self.cols:
                sns.boxplot(x=col,y='Ex-Showroom_Price',data=self.data[self.data['Ex-Showroom_Price']])


    

df=pd.read_csv('cars_engage_2022.csv')
cols=['Make','Model','City_Mileage','Highway_Mileage','ARAI_Certified_Mileage','Type','Fuel_Type','Body_Type']
d=Vizualizer(df,cols)
df["Ex-Showroom_Price"] = df["Ex-Showroom_Price"].str.replace(r'.* ([\d,]+)+$', r'\1',regex=True).str.replace(',', '',regex=True).astype('int32')
d.box_plot()
```

**ERROR**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\shweta\OneDrive\Desktop\DEMO\demo\src\carsengage2022\preprocessing\roughVIZ.py", line 36, in <module>
    d.box_plot()
  File "c:\Users\shweta\OneDrive\Desktop\DEMO\demo\src\carsengage2022\preprocessing\roughVIZ.py", line 25, in box_plot
    sns.boxplot(x=col,y='Ex-Showroom_Price',data=self.data[self.data['Ex-Showroom_Price']])
  File "C:\Users\shweta\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 3511, in __getitem__
    indexer = self.columns._get_indexer_strict(key, "columns")[1]
  File "C:\Users\shweta\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 5782, in _get_indexer_strict
    self._raise_if_missing(keyarr, indexer, axis_name)
  File "C:\Users\shweta\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 5842, in _raise_if_missing
    raise KeyError(f"None of [{key}] are in the [{axis_name}]")
KeyError: "None of [Int64Index([ 292667,  236447,  296661,  334768,  272223,  314815,  279650,\n             351832,  333419,  362000,\n            ...\n    
        1065900, 1182000, 1312000, 1111000, 1191000, 1302000, 1421000,\n            1431000, 1201000, 6862560],\n           dtype='int64', length=1276)] are 
in the [columns]"
```

I'm trying to plot a boxplot between the columns in cols and their Ex-Showroom-Price.
The values of the Ex-Showroom-Price are categorical, therefore, I first converted them to integer and then I'm trying to do the boxplot ,but it's throwing the error that,Key Error: "None of [Int64Index...] dtype='int64] are in the columns".

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to either swap around these lines

```
df["Ex-Showroom_Price"] = df["Ex-Showroom_Price"].str.replace(r'.* ([\d,]+)+$', r'\1',regex=True).str.replace(',', '',regex=True).astype('int32')
d=Vizualizer(df,cols)
```

Or make sure you are editing the dataframe in the class by:

```
d=Vizualizer(df,cols)
d.df["Ex-Showroom_Price"] = df["Ex-Showroom_Price"].str.replace(r'.* ([\d,]+)+$', r'\1',regex=True).str.replace(',', '',regex=True).astype('int32')
```